# Question about polynomials of odd degree with no zeros in formally real fields which are maximal to the property of being ordered

Tags: field-theory, model-theory, ordered-fields

I have encountered this argument while reading Tent and Ziegler's "Course in model theory", and I don't know why it is justified.
It arises during the proof that every ordered field has a real closure.

Let $R$ be an ordered field, and let $f\in R[X]$ be a polynomial of odd degree without a zero. Now let $\alpha$ be a zero for $f$ in the algebraic closure of $R$ and put $L=R(\alpha)$. It follows from prior arguments that $L$ cannot be ordered (as $R$ was constructed to be maximal with regard to this property), and so $-1$ is a sum of squares in $L$. Why does it follow that there are polynomials $g_i \in R[X]$ of degree less than $n$ such that $f$ divides $1+\sum g_i^2$?

Thanks

Comment: You really should write down the assumptions about $R$ that are being used ... As it stands, we're left to guess as to the way in which it is maximal, for instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $L$ are of the form $g(\alpha)$ with $g(x)\in R[x]$, $\deg g<n$. If
$$
-1=\sum_{i=1}^kg_i(\alpha)^2
$$
for some $g_i(x)\in R[x], i=1,2,\ldots,k,$ then $\alpha$ is a zero of the polynomial
$$
p(x)=1+\sum_i g_i(x)^2\in R[x].
$$
Because $R$ is ordered, $p(x)$ cannot be the constant polynomial zero (think about the coefficient of degree $2\max\{\deg g_i\mid i=1,2,\ldots,k\}$). Therefore $p(x)$ must be divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, i.e. $f(x)$

Comment: I now observe that you didn't require $f$ to be irreducible. Without that extra assumption the claim may be false or ... may be it still holds? Anyway $f$ must have an irreducible factor of an odd degree. Can you work with that instead of $f$? Gotta rush now...

Comment: That's not a problem. Irreducibility can be obtained by requiring that $f$ is of minimal degree satisfying the conditions.

Comment: @Shai Deshe It can be, but you don't get that $f$ divides the resulting sum. I'd provide a counterexample, but it's hard without the context, especially as it seems to be a reasoning by contradiction, so no actual examples exist...